# Transpose columns in table

Tags: code-golf, array

Let's say you've got a table of data:

```
meter_id date   0000 0600 1200 1800
0        030915 10   20   30   40
1        030915 15   7    49   2
```

where the last four columns are meter readings at different times. You want to output

```
meter_id date   time reading
0        030915 0000 10
0        030915 0600 20
```

etc.

Your input and output will *not* have headers, unlike in this example. The set of columns you'll transpose will be provided as numeric arguments to your program, from 1 onwards. Input is stdin and output is stdout.

So here's an example of it actually being used.

```
$ ./tpose 3 4 5 6
```

Stdin:

```
0        030915 10   20   30   40
1        030915 15   7    49   2
```

Stdout:

```
0       030915  3       10
0       030915  4       20
0       030915  5       30
0       030915  6       40
1       030915  3       15
1       030915  4       7
1       030915  5       49
1       030915  6       2
```

The third column contains values from 3 to 6. This is because the reading is from columns 3 to 6 from the input table.

Happy golfing.

Comment: Can you post some example inputs and outputs?

Comment: Is `0600 30` in the example just wrong (1200 is 30), or are you trying to do cumulative readings (so adding the current 20 to the previous 10)?

Comment: @Geobits Fixed.

Comment: You say in the text that the values in the third column of the output are 3 to 6, but they are actually 2 to 5. Which one is right? Right now, it looks like you're using 1-based column indices in the input, and 0-based in the output.

Comment: @RetoKoradi fixed

Comment: Can the input and output columns be separated by a single space? Or a single tab?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos whichever

Comment: Do the columns to be transposed always form a contiguous range? Can other columns appear after them? If yes, where should the transposed columns appear in the output? Are the columns to be transposed always given in ascending order, and can they contain the same column twice? And if so, can we reorder them in the output, or collapse duplicates?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The argument is a list of individual columns. They do not have to be contiguous. The new columns should be at the end. As far as the same column being supplied twice, that case is pathological and you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Order is otherwise unimportant.

Comment: not to be pedantic, but isn't the more normalizing than transposing?

Comment: Can we take the table as an argument instead of from stdin?

Comment: Can we assume the input table's records are unique?

Comment: @Adám I'd prefer it from stdin. You can assume the records are unique.

Comment: @manandlaptop How about as JSON (or other format) from stdin? Or via stdin getting a filename to read from?

Comment: @Adám JSON, no. Getting a filename from stdin, if it helps, you may do that.

Comment: Does the list of column numbers have to come from the command line, or can it be a function argument?

Comment: Can you give an example of what is permitted when the selected columns are not contiguous?

Comment: @dfeuer What in *numeric arguments to your program* makes you think that function arguments are disallowed?

Comment: @Adám, nothing. I just noticed almost all the answers used command line arguments.

Answer (score 3):

## kdb k, 101 bytes

```
1@"\n"/:{"\n"/:{" "/:(r@&{~#&x=a}'!#r),(,$1+a@x),,c@x}'!#c::(r::" "\:x)@a::-1+.:'.z.x}'-1_"\n"\:0::0;
```

**Me:** *(reads the word "transpose" in the title)* K will be perfect for this! It'll kick everything else's hind!

*20 minutes and 101 bytes later*

**Me:** Idiot.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>88</s> 84 bytes

Input is tab-separated. Annoyingly, Ruby `gets` pulls from files whose names match those from `ARGV`, but those don't exist so the program errors out. To work around this, I have to use `STDIN.gets` to get the actual correct input.

-4 bytes by remembering that I don't actually need to use `scan` since I'm only matching the pattern once per line anyways, so `=~` for a single regex match saves bytes.

```ruby
($_=~/(\d+	\w+	)(.*)/;i=-1;puts$2.split.map{|s|"#$1#{$*[i+=1]}	"+s})while STDIN.gets
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PchBC4IwFADg8@tXhO4wHc23uRUi3rp06VK3jCiSGhhIm0io/fXXre/4vfvbh4izS/XNeH0XUA8CEi7TJCtdtVJl1wfPtPRd64J8Xbtx8lMUMxWPLD05UanzDJHwczI8XdssD8ftbi8fTfBECJhjoSwoBI2QIxhcqH9a2IApQFNOhiytfw)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (195 bytes)

```
import System.Environment
main=do s<-getArgs>>=return.map(\a->read a-1);interact$unlines.map unwords.t s.map words.lines
t g r=[[a!!j|j<-[0..length a-1],not$j`elem`g]++show(j+1):[a!!j]|a<-r,j<-g]
```

Ungolfed Haskell (398 bytes):

```
import System.Environment
import Prelude

main = do js <- getArgs >>= return . map (\a -> read a - 1)
          interact $ unbr . (`tpose` js) . br

br = map words . lines

xs `excludingFrom` es = [xs !! j | j <- [0..length xs - 1], not $ j `elem` es]

tpose rows js = [row `excludingFrom` js ++ [show (j+1)] ++ [row !! j] | row <- rows, j <- js]

unbr = unlines . map (foldr1 $ \t a -> t++"\t"++a)
```

Comment: `p>>=return.f` should generally be written `f<$>p`. In this case, though, you can golf more by just using `s<-getArgs` and applying the parsing inline. Since you use `map` three times, you should write `m=map` on its own line and use that.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 87 bytes

```
perl -E'while(<STDIN>){@f=(0,split);@i=0..$#f,@i[@ARGV]=0;say"@f[grep$_,@i] $_ $f[$_]"for@ARGV}'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 90 bytes

```php
while($r=fgetcsv(STDIN,0,' '))foreach($argv as$a)if($a|0)echo"$r[0] $r[1] $a {$r[$a-1]}
";
```

Input and output with [single space delimiter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60185/transpose-columns-in-table/187363#comment144859_60185).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcixCsIwFIXhvU9xKYEmUOGmSStFxcXFxUU36RBC0hSEhlTqoD77NZPLx39ODJH2x5h9henhOEsHP7qnXVZ@vZ3OlxrrCioh/JycsYEzk8YVzMKMmHxeHxTOhrlk6Y4DZGXWwDsXMxs5fItyR4SACnvZgkRoEBSCxkL@zxa2oHtoSJGmlrof)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 109 bytes

```php
while($r=preg_split("/\s+/",fgets(STDIN),0,1))foreach($argv as$a)if($a|0)echo"$r[0]\t$r[1]\t$a\t{$r[$a-1]}
";
```

Or with I/O exactly as shown above, using fixed width columns.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYq9CsIwFIX3PkUJGRKs9Ma2SlFxcXFx0c0WCSVtCoWGJOigPvs1ASfP8J0fjtEGdwcT@NTjpBi1e2PVcHdmGj0jeeMWOcn6QXnHLtfj6cwzyATn/WyV7DSj0g6PVDoq@diH9gauOj0Tam/QNj6YiCYb/wqZyqVoPwnZIkL6ExRQiyoVcVhFFBElJOL/UYW8iUNZxy8WWGKF6y8)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 56 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous prefix lambda. Takes column numbers for "transposition" as right argument and [prompts via stdin for filename](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60185/transpose-columns-in-table#comment449337_60185) of table.

```apl
{(t[;⍵~⍨⍳≢⍉t]⌿⍨≢⍵),(⍪,⍨⍵⍴⍨≢),t[;⍵]⊣t←↑(∊∘⎕D⊆⊢)¨⊃⎕NGET⍞1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/@vXlKQX5yqV1JRov6ob6pfQGjIo94Vj7qa1A0UDIwNLA1NFQwNFIwMFIwNFEwM1BXUDeHCpgrmCiaWCkbq/6s1SqKtH/VurQNp7d38qHPRo97OkthHPftBAiDeVk0djUe9q3TACrY@6t0CkdDUgWiMfdS1uORR24RHbRM1HnV0PeqYAXSLy6OutkddizQPAZ3TDHKbuyvQbfMMa/@DnQxS3ttnDJELDnIGkiEensFcXEAGUA6sRsFYwUTBVMHsP9yTAA)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; right argument (column numbers) is `⍵`:

`⍞1` prompt for file name from stdin and juxtapose with `1` (indicating that we want a list of strings)
  `["tpose",1]`

`⎕NGET` **get** the **n**ative file's (content,encoding,newline)
  `[["0 030915 10 20 30 40","1 030915 15 7 49 2"],"UTF-8-NOBOM",[10]]`

`⊃` pick the first of those (content)
  `["0 030915 10 20 30 40","1 030915 15 7 49 2"]`

`(`…`)¨` apply the following tacit function to each line:

`∊` the characters that are members
  `∘` of
  `⎕D` the set of **d**igits
   `[[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1],[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]]`

`⊆` indicate the sub-partitions of

`⊢` the line
   `[["0","030915","10","20","30","40"],["1","030915","15","7","49","2"]]`

`↑` up the rank by mixing the list (rank 1) of lists into a matrix (rank 2)
  `[["0","030915","10","20","30","40"],`
   `["1","030915","15","7" ,"49","2" ]]`

`t←` assign that to `t` (for **t**able)

`⊣` discard that in favour of

`t[;⍵]` all rows of the subset of columns of `t` enumerated in the argument
  `[["10","20","30","40"],`
   `["15","7" ,"49","2" ]]`

`,` ravel (flatten that)
  `["10","20","30","40","15","7","49","2"]`

`(`…`)` apply the following tacit function to that:

`≢` the tally of elements
   `8`

`⍵⍴⍨` use that to reshape the number of columns to be "transposed"
   `[3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6]`

`,⍨` to that, append

`⍪` the table-fied (made into single-column table) argument (the "transposed" columns)
  `[[3,"10"],`
   `[4,"20"],`
   `[5,"30"],`
   `[6,"40"],`
   `[3,"15"],`
   `[4,"7" ],`
   `[5,"49"],`
   `[6,"2" ]]`

`(`…`),` prepend the following:

`≢⍵` the tally of columns to be "transposed"
   `4`

…`⌿⍨` use that to vertically replicate the rows of…

`t[;`…`]` all rows of the following columns of the table:

`⍉t` transpose the table
     `[["0"     ,"1"     ],`
      `["030915","030915"],`
      `["10"    ,"15"    ],`
      `["20"    ,"7"     ],`
      `["30"    ,"49"    ],`
      `["40"    ,"2"     ]]`

`≢` the tally of rows
     `6`

`⍳` **ɩ**ndices until that
     `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

`⍵~⍨` except the "transposed" column numbers
     `[1,2]`

`[["0","030915"],`
    `["1","030915"]]`

`[["0","030915"],`
   `["0","030915"],`
   `["0","030915"],`
   `["0","030915"],`
   `["1","030915"],`
   `["1","030915"],`
   `["1","030915"],`
   `["1","030915"]]`

`[["0","030915",3,"10"],`
  `["0","030915",4,"20"],`
  `["0","030915",5,"30"],`
  `["0","030915",6,"40"],`
  `["1","030915",3,"15"],`
  `["1","030915",4,"7" ],`
  `["1","030915",5,"49"],`
  `["1","030915",6,"2" ]]`